# How to read Facebook photo comments in Android Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-fql

Any one have idea, how to get photo comment using Android Facebook SDK.
I am performing normal FQL to perform other operation.

Thanks

Comment: How can i get id for which you enter in url?

Answer (score 1):

you can get photo comments in graph API simply by quering photo id like so:
https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305
https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305/comments

or in FQL you should use a "comment" table:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/
using photo "object_id" which you can get from "photo" table having a photo "pid"

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Anatoly : i also trying same from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/ ...and trying to execute an demo query like: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=select+post_fbid%2C+fromid%2C+object_id%2C+text%2C+time+from+comment+where+object_id+1602217650 ...but it return me an file which contain some error log in JSON formate.. pls let me know any suggestion. thanks

Comment: you have wrong syntax, see the following query for example of correct FQL: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=select+post_fbid,fromid,object_id,text,time+from+comment+where+object_id=98423808305

Comment: I m using same using photo_id = 100000251913304_620941
https://graph.facebook.com/100000251913304_620941/comments

it replying me blank json data..pls suggest me what i am missing here.

Comment: I used an https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305/comments with same permission ..working perfectly fine..but for me like for id = 100000251913304_620941...not working ...returning blank json object.

Comment: @AnatolyLubarsky How can i get id for which you enter in url ?

Comment: @Shubh How can i get id for which you enter in url

Comment: Hi Harshal..I did it long back so not remember..probably u can go with mention above answer with some digging yourself..also u can ask at FB developer forum as well.

Comment: @Harshal Kalavadiya: i.e. via FQL: select object_id from photo where pid=[YOUR_PHOTO_ID]

Comment: I am at same situation with Shubh. I am getting blank json response