# How to get Facebook photo TAG using FQL?

Tags: android, facebook

Any one have idea how can get TAG of facebook photos using FQL?

Comment: Hi Shubh, tou already asked this question yesterday, you should continue discussing the answers on the same post so avoid diluting the information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329367/how-to-read-facebook-photo-comments-in-android-facebook-sdk

Comment: thanks..but i asking for Photo tag .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have simply the **[photo_tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/)** Table and there is fields like text you can query,as

`SELECT text FROM photo_tag WHERE pid ='pid'` where pid is The ID of the photo being queried

Comment: thanks, but what happened if i want to fetch photo tag of my frinds album also

Comment: Use multi query. First query: get albums fids of your friends. Seconds - get photos fids of this albums.